# how to take a screenshot of the entire webpage?

Tags: selenium

I am very new to all the technologies so can any one suggest what tool can I use to take screenshot of entire web page along with the URL.

These screenshots would be taken every quarterly, and after a quarter it will be compared with the last quarter's screenshot. It will be compared on the basis of major changes made on web page

I have to do this for 100's of domains.

Please suggest 
1.Tool to take screen shot
2.How to compare.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium & imacro can help u taking the browser screenshot

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool in existence which can perform above specified tasks.

You can easily find tools for capturing screenshots, but you will be not able to view changes done after a specified time. You need to develop a crawler to perform this task. You can pick PHP or .net as technology to handle this task.

In case, you have any query, you can let us know anytime.

Thank You

Comment: How write code to take screenshot of the last opened page of chrome without using any external library  ? Sir is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below selenium code

File file = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

Where driver is Webdriver object (e.g. WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of iMacros solution.

http://wiki.imacros.net/SCREENSHOT

```
 URL GOTO=http://www.iopus.com/imacros/home/v9/home.asp
 SCREENSHOT TYPE=Page FOLDER=* FILE=*
 SCREENSHOT TYPE=Browser FOLDER=* FILE=*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshot using selenium web driver code , See below :

http://www.ontestautomation.com/how-to-create-screenshots-in-your-selenium-webdriver-tests/